# Django filter many-to-many from an id

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a problem, I'm coding with python/django.
I have this kind of models.py :

```
class Skill(models.Model):
name = models.CharField()
    skill=models.ForeignKey(Skill)

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    skill= models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

And my problem is: I want to print for one Job, all the skills which are attached.
Example: I have the Developer Job, with the ID=4 (in my db), and I want to print all the
skill which are attached with the Developer Job.

Tks !!

Comment: Why is there a ForeignKey on Skill pointing to itself?

Comment: Ho sorry, it's a mistake, i edited it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Job item already, in a variable called `my_job`:

```
my_job.skill.all()
```

If you just have the ID:

```
Skill.objects.filter(job__id=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will also find useful a possibility to get to get all Jobs, which are referenced bu some Skill. It's easy like that:

```
ninja_skill = Skill.objects.get(name='ninja')
jobs_with_ninja_skill = ninja_skill.job_set.all()
```